# How to rearrange columns in libreoffice calc as per column totals?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have the final row as total which has the sum for each column.I wish to rearrange the columns such that the columns from left to right will be arranged descendingly as per column total.

Comment: You should give some dummy example to avoid any confusion. Or post the screenshot, otherwise this won't help much for further users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I selected all data then from top menu went to -> Data tab -> then sort -> then options -> Direction left to right -> Sort criteria -> sort key 1 -> column with Total